# Plotting a function of two variables that includes a vector inside

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following problem and this is the minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
def f1(x,y,scal):
    return np.exp(-(scal-x)/y)
def f2(x,y,vec):
    return np.sum(np.exp(-(vec-x)/y))

inputvec = np.arange(1,10,1)

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(1,8,1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z1 = f1(X,Y,20)
print Z1
Z2 = f2(X,Y,inputvec)
```

I want to 3D plot the function f2, so this is why I try the meshgrid thing. The error is:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (7,10)
```

It is even clear to me why this is the case, python would I think like to do something like f1, so that Z1 can be a grid answer which you can plot. But what if I use a vector in my function and the very nasty sum operation.

Question: How can I change my function f2 to get around this problem, or is there a different way to (3D, Contour, etc..) plot f2 without going via the meshgrid way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the problem is that you are trying to do `vec-x`, where `vec.shape=(9,)` and `X.shape=(7,10)`. What exactly do you expect that calculation to output?

Comment: I tried to explain that with f1. Ultimately I want to plot a function of two variables that has a single number as output, so is plotable. If you were to enter x and y as numbers the function works fine. But when I enter the mesh grid as input, well as you said, then it doesn't work anymore.. I know why, just don't know how else to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear from your question, but I *think* you want:

```
def f3(x,y,vec):
    return np.sum(np.exp(-(vec[:, None, None] - x[None]) / y[None]), 0)
```

Indexing with `None` (or equivalently, with `np.newaxis`) inserts a new dimension of size 1, so `vec[:, None, None]` has shape `(9, 1, 1)` and `x[None]` and `y[None]` have shapes `(1, 7, 10)`. `vec[:,  None, None] - x[None]` then gets [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) out to shape `(10, 7, 9)`. Finally, we compute the sum over just the first dimension using `np.sum(..., 0)` to yield a `(7, 10)` array that looks like this:

```
Z3 = f3(X, Y, inputvec)
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z3)
```

[image]

---

Another useful tool that simplifies operations like this is [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html), which constructs an "open grid" from a set of input vectors that is suitable for broadcasting over:

```
v_, y_, x_ = np.ix_(inputvec, y, x)     # here x and y are 1D
z = np.sum(np.exp(-(v_ - x_) / y_), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted! How can I formulate the question better, I guess I did not know about broadcasting! Also, your version didn't exactly work I think, I'll make some quick changes, let me know if you agree! (Broadcasting starts at trailing dimension I think..)

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think my version doesn't work? Broadcasting can occur over *any* dimension depending on the shapes of the input arrays (see "General Broadcasting Rules" in the documentation I linked to).

Comment: I think it is this feature: "It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when:
1. they are equal, or
2. **one of them is 1** ". So the trailing dimension of the 3D array is 10, where the one of the inputvec is 9. This is why I got the error: "<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape". Transposing fixes that, because it matches the axes, that need to be put together.

Comment: Sorry, that was me being careless - I had reshaped your `inputvec` variable already in my IPython session and forgotten about it. You could either use `x[None].T` and broadcast over the last dimension, as in your suggested edit, or you could insert extra dimensions in `vec` and broadcast over the first,  as in my update. I also mentioned `np.ix_` which lets you avoid explicitly creating 2D grids for `X` and `Y` (see `np.ogrid` as well). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. Ironically my problem turns out to be even more complicated, but that is far outside the scope of this question...